# how to obtain and match Google's Print Page link calling it in a userscript

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I want to delete a certain element from google's print page by injecting a userscript. However, i can't find the matching link to replace the question-marks in the @match row

```
 // ==UserScript==
 // @name         test
 // @namespace    http://your.homepage/
 // @version      0.1
 // @description  enter something useful
 // @author       You
 // @match        ??????????
 // @grant        none
 // @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
 // ==/UserScript==


  $("#copies-settings").remove();
```

Comment: Provide a link or a recipe to what you are calling "google's print page".

Comment: hi and thanks for ur reply. I mean the popup than appears when u press ctrl P on ggl chrome.